# converting xsd date format using xslt

Tags: xslt, xsd

The following is the xsd format I've currently got:

2012-08-23T00:05:27Z

I want to convert this into the following xsl format:

08/23/2012 05:27 AM

---

xsl:value-of select="@CreatedDate" />

CreatedDate is my variable.

Comment: which programming language you are using ?

Comment: I have created that column in Sharepoint 2013 using datetime datatype. I'm editing that column using Sharepoint designer .

Comment: By the way, those times don't match - 00:05:27 is 27 seconds after 5 minutes past midnight, not 5:27 AM.

Comment: XSLT 1.0 or 2.0? In 2.0, it's trivial using format-date().

Comment: XSLT 1.0 @ Michael Kay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is about XSLT (which I am not at all sure about), the following code:

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(
              substring(@CreatedDate, 6, 2), '/',
              substring(@CreatedDate, 9, 2), '/',
              substring(@CreatedDate, 1, 4)
              )"/>
```

will produce a result of `"08/23/2012"`. The rest is left as an exercise for the reader. :-)

Comment: thank you very much its working for me @ user3016153. still working for time format.